# Make filters sidebar disappear

Tags: filter, prestashop

I would like to give users the ability to hide the filters sidebar so that it appears and disappears at the push of a button. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, this feature is not included in the PrestaShop, but you can create it.

Add the new button for example to the *themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/category-header.tpl*

```
<button class="btn" id="show_hide_filter">Show/hide filters</button>
```

and with manipulate the DOM with jQuery

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $('#show_hide_filter').click(function () {
      if($("#left-column").is(":visible")){
        $("#left-column").hide();
        $('#content-wrapper').addClass('col-lg-12');
      }else{
        $("#left-column").show();
        $('#content-wrapper').removeClass('col-lg-12');
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: @GianMarcoDiMingo Glad I could help!
Please mark my answer as a solution so that others can easily find if they encounter a similar error.
Thanks.